# Send value even for unchecked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form with 4 checkboxes like this:

```
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name = "all_post" value="0" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "all_post" id = "all_post" value="1"> All Posts <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name = "others_post" value="0" checked> 
    <input type="checkbox" name = "others_post" id = "others_post" value="1"> Other's Posts <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name = "clients_post" value="0" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "clients_post" id = "clients_post" value="1"> Cilent's Post <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name = "assigned_post" value="0" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "assigned_post" id = "assigned_post" value="1"> Task Assigned 
  </td>
```

If a checkbox is checked, I want it to return "1" but if it is unchecked I want it to return "0" thus I have a hidden checkbox with the same name. My server handles checkboxes in that it will send both hidden and unhidden checkbox values of ("0","1") and I only want to receive one value. All the hidden checkboxes are checked by default to send "0" but I want to make it so that if the unhidden checkbox is checked then the hidden one will become unchecked so only 1 value gets sent. How would I approach that?

**TL:DR**
I want to send a value of "0" if an option is not checked and "1" if an option is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, the code below may help you. However i didn't understand why you are trying to use not only checkbox and hidden input with checked attribute but also oppositely.

Change HTML like this, because you don't need the hidden inputs as you are going to validate data with name and if all you want is just 1 or 0, the code in below may help you.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eaVL3/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "all_post" id = "all_post" value="0"> All Posts <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "others_post" id = "others_post" value="0"> Other's Posts <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "clients_post" id = "clients_post" value="0"> Cilent's Post <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "assigned_post" id = "assigned_post" value="0"> Task Assigned
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked == true)
            $(this).val("1"); 
        else
            $(this).val("0");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but it isn't working 100%. When I make the hidden checkboxes unhidden to test them, everything works. But I put them to hidden, both their values get send, hiddena and unhidden

Comment: i'm not sure if i understood what you want again but i've edited both my answer and fiddle. After this maybe you can just validate the sent data with which one is 1 or 0 as i've updated them when checkbox is checked, it's value gets 0, if not checked it's value gets 1.

Comment: Your code makes sense, but I dont know why but it keeps sending two values. Maybe its a Perl thing?

Comment: But basically when a checkbox is checked it returns "1" and when it isnt, no value gets sent, but I want a value of "0" to be sent when an option isn't checked. Perhaps theres another way to approach this?

Comment: i think i got what you want, you can just remove the hidden inputs. i'll we updating my answer soon.

Comment: For some reason, it doesnt change the value to 1. It just submits "0", if checked or null, if unchecked

Comment: is jquery included in your file?

Comment: Ah nvm, it was a snytax error. Your script works. But when a box is not checked it sends over null. When checked it sends over 1

Comment: The "0" still isn't being sent because the checkboxes are unchecked when their value is "0" and they return null.

Comment: check the checkboxes' value with their input names in the perl, not with their checked attribute.

Comment: any progress you have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use a radio button](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Take this example of male/female. It sounds like you want it to either return male, or female, not "0-male,1-female". So, with a radio button,

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

This will make it so the user can only select one value, and the one value is returned. Checkbox is the wrong form for your purposes.